# Select row to display in Shiny data table with selectInput

Tags: shiny, reactive

I'm new to figuring out reactivity in shiny. I want to use selectInput to choose the name of a row and have the table display just that row and then several columns.

For example, if my rows are people ("Anna","Tim","Larry") and my columns are variables ("A","B","C") I want the selectInput to show "Anna" and the data table to display variables A,B, and C for only Anna.

I'm stuck on how to do this.

```
 ui <- shinyUI(
 fluidPage(
 fluidRow(
column(2, selectInput("name", "Select a Name:",
                      c("Anna"= "smith.anna",
                        "Tim" = "miller.tim"))),
column(6, "People Table", tableOutput("mytable")
 ))))

 server <- function(input, output) {
 output$mytable <- renderTable({
 mydataset[mydataset, input$name]})
 }
```

I'm pretty sure it's my server functionality that's messed up,  but all tips are helpful! Thanks!

Comment: mydataset[mydataset, input$name] seems to be the problem. Do you maybe mean mydataset[input$name, ] ? Anyway, a reproducible example is always helpful if you are seeking help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment:

```
mydataset <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
row.names(mydataset) <- c("smith.anna", "miller.tim", "page.larry")


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(2, selectInput("name", "Select a Name:",
                            c("Anna"= "smith.anna",
                              "Tim" = "miller.tim"))),
      column(6, "People Table", tableOutput("mytable")
      ))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    mydataset[input$name, ]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Really helpful! Thank you!